# regex - redirect everything except one folder and its content

Tags: regex, url, redirect, directory

So, I need to 301 redirect one whole site to another (without keeping the path), except one folder - webinars - and its content. Examples:

```
oldsite.com                 > newsite.com
oldsite.com/?id=2           > newsite.com
oldsite.com/test/           > newsite.com
oldsite.com/abc/?id=2       > newsite.com
oldsite.com/test/abc/       > newsite.com

oldsite.com/webinars/       > do nothing
oldsite.com/webinars/?id=1  > do nothing
oldsite.com/webinars/abc/   > do nothing
```

What I tried is this regex rule (https://regex101.com/r/vpc3qv/1):

REDIRECT FROM: `^(?!\/webinars\/).*`

REDIRECT TO: `newsite.com`

But it doesn't work as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. Can you please be more specific in your request? What is the expected output? What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I need a regex rule for a nginx server that will redirect anyone who visits oldsite.com to newsite.com, except when people visit the webinars folder on the old site (oldsite.com/webinars/*)

Comment: Try this regex: `^(?![a-zA-z.]*\/webinar).*` Working example: https://regex101.com/r/EUJqcP/2/

Comment: Did it solve your question ?